# multicast and unicast

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, bluetooth

i'm doing a project regarding proximity marketing through BLE.
for that we are going to create a bluetooth beacon from raspberry pi 3.0.
I need to know whether  raspberry pi can transmit multicast and unicast signals other than the broadcast.i'm going to program to the raspberry pi using python. please help me

Comment: Your question is a little confusing due to the tags you've applied - your question text says you're using a Pi 3 but your tags include pi-2, which would change the answers significantly. Could you please review your question text or tags to clarify which model you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am going to stretch a limb and say I am working with `socket` modules in Python and I send out information using **Multicasting** the only difference is I use **WLAN** as my medium of transfer. I presume you do the same with **Bluetooth LE** also. I have created a class which sets the socket of my interest as a Multicast IPv6 port and I send an receive data on it because I have configured my `wlan0` interface to be able to use the IPv6 multicast.

I have a [Repository](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/FountainCodes/blob/master/twinSocket.py) where you can use this Python Socket Class for your usage or trial.

**Note**: the repository code is issued under GPLv3 License.

I hope it helps.

Comment: If you think this is the thing you want you can up vote and accept it. Thanks :)